# Arduino and GPS module Neo 6m

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-leonardo, gps

I have an Arduino Leonardo and a GPS module "NEO 6M"

Pinout:

```
PPS->free   
rxd->11   
txd->10  
gnd->gnd   
vcc->5v
```

I'm running this code:

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial gps(10,11);
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gps.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  while (gps.available())
    Serial.write(gps.read());
}
```

In serial monitor I'm getting random characters like this

[image: Screenshot of serial monitor]

Where am I going wrong?

I tried the same with an Arduino Mega but have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: GPS module was broken. Now I use another GPS module, same model. Sorry for my English.

Comment: How did you ascertain that the module was broken? Did you try it with a different GPS module and it then worked? Could you edit and expand your answer a little, as it could be useful for someone else who has the same issue...

Comment: i used another GPS module and resolve all my problem :) sorry for late response